# JDBC SocketTimeoutException to MSSQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I try to connect to an MS SQL Server via JDBC. Everything works fine if only my Java program is started. If the SQL Server Management Studio is started on the same machine on the same machine - to test some statements - I get the following error when I run the java programm:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host   XXXXXX, named instance YYYYYY failed.
>
> Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out".
>
> Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking    UDP traffic to port 1434.
>
> For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

If I close MS SQL Server Management Studio I must wait about 30 minutes if I can run the java programm again without errors.

So what can I do that I can connect with JDBC and run MS SQL Server Management Studio at the same time on the same machine? Or at least what can I do that after the close of the SQL Server Management Studio I must not wait 30 minutes.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Can you share us the Connection string and the code how you are trying to connect to this MS SQL Server instance?

Comment: Hi, my connection string is "jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+";user="+user+";password="+password  and I connect using this String via DriverManager.getConnection

Comment: This should be your connection string (`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=instance1;integratedSecurity=true;`) based on your inputs. Follow [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) for reference!

Comment: Hi, the timeout problem occurs also if I use your connection string.

Comment: What does `SELECT @@MAX_CONNECTIONS AS maxconn;` tell you?

Comment: Hi Gord, maxconn is 32767